# mercurial kdiff3 mac is not opening

Tags: macos, mercurial, merge, kdiff3

I am using eclipse with mercurial on my new mac and
when I am trying to merge it gives me a message
"1 file unresolved" and kdiff3 it's not opening ,
kdiff3 is the default merge tool right ?
If not how can I configure it ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if Eclipse cuts in but for Mercurial itself the default merge tool is its internal merge. For kdiff3 this seemed to work for me:

*.hgrc*

```
[ui]
merge = macfilemerge

[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.difftool = diff-w

[merge-tools]
macfilemerge.executable = diff-w
macfilemerge.args = $base $local $other -o $output
```

*diff-w*

```
# Piping the output makes the script to wait for diff tool's output
/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 "$@" | cat
```

Remember to chmod +x your *diff-w* and put it somewhere in your common paths.

### Other merge tools

**Filemerge**

*.hgrc*

```
[merge-tools]
macfilemerge.args = $local $other -ancestor $base -merge $output
```

*diff-w*

```
opendiff "$@" | cat
```

**P4Merge**

*.hgrc*

```
[merge-tools]
macfilemerge.args = $base $local $other $output
```

*diff-w*

```
/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge "$@" | cat
```